# Style XML element in code block messes up syntax highlighting coloring

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

If you put some XML in a code block (by indenting by 4 spaces) and one of the tags is `<Style>` it will mess up the syntax highlighting of the generated result.

This works:

```xml
<Style2 Foo="ThisWillWork">
   <!-- Stuff in here is colored ok -->
   <SomeElement Bar="Baz" />
</Style2>
```

While this won't:

```xml
<Style Foo="ThisWontWork">
   <!-- stuff in here won't be properly colored -->
   <SomeElement Bar="Baz" />
</Style>
```

The problem is both in the JS preview as well as the rendered result.

In case this cannot be reproduced, here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: screenshot of the error]

For reference:

- Using Google Chrome 8.0.552.215
- I first saw this issue when answering [ScatterViewItem Custom Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135454/scatterviewitem-custom-shape) on Dec 7 2010

Comment: This problem still exists. For reference see [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942782/how-to-use-visualstates-to-set-visibility-of-templatedparent)

Comment: I deleted the question in question, so the link above is >=10k only.

Comment: Here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183230/silverlight-togglebutton-checked-visualstate-not-working)

Comment: And [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/432573/1521227) (Will stop posting examples here now...) ;)

Comment: Also observed with IE 9.0.8112.16421 and SRWare Iron 20.0.1150.1

Comment: FYI, this is simply an issue with prettify treating the content of a `<style>` element as CSS and highlighting it accordingly *regardless of whether the code block is HTML or XML*. So it's not the syntax highlighting acting strange nor is it a browser bug - it's just the highlighting script making the same assumptions and decisions at the wrong times. The same happens with content of `<script>` elements being treated as JavaScript as well.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn that didn't occur to me. Could you please post that as an answer because that solves this question I think. Maybe I will make a new feature-request for treating `lang-xml` and `lang-html` differently one day...

Comment: @Spontifixus: Your best bet there is to file a bug report with Google Code Prettify, which is what SE uses. They don't maintain the syntax highlighting code, and the most you'd get out of them for these types of things is them filing the bug report *for* you.

Comment: @animuson Thank you for that hint. I will have a look at their bug-tracker. However I think that this "bug" is likely to be marked as "by-design" according to what BoltClock said in the comments here...

Comment: I filed a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=280

Comment: When a question is [tagged as xhtml and xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml+xhtml) or [html and xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+xml), what kind of highlighting ought be done for code sections without explicit `<!-- language: ... -->` markers?  Is it desired that `<script>` bodies; and event handler, URL, and `style` attributes also not be specially handled?

Comment: Marking this question as a duplicate of the 'what is syntax highlighting' q written 3 years later, means I didn't find this much more specific answer to my question while searching, and meant I just posted a duplicate of _this_ question :( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332437/xml-syntax-highlighting-bug-for-style-elements