# XML syntax highlighting bug for "<style>" elements

Tags: bug, meta, syntax-highlighting, xml

The following XML fragment has incorrect syntax highlighting for comments and nested attributes:

```xml
<style name="MyApp.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar">
    <!-- This comment should be grey -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
</style>
```

The following similar fragment looks better:

```xml
<stylez name="MyApp.ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar">
    <!-- This comment should be grey -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
</stylez>
```

Spot the difference. By changing `<stylez>` to `<style>`:

- Comment text is black instead of grey
- The `item` element is black instead of brown
- The `item.name` attribute black instead of red
- The `item.name` attribute value is brown instead of blue

Here's a META image of this post, for reference if using a different theme, or for when this issue is fixed:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: This appears to be an actual issue with the syntax highlighter, which is not maintained by Stack Exchange, and should be reported to the maintainer of the syntax highlighter, Prettify. See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: My q is actually a duplicate of this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71649/style-xml-element-in-code-block-messes-up-syntax-highlighting-coloring which I didn't find before posting, because that itself is also marked as a duplicate of the same 'what is syntax highlighting' q :(
The real answer is an 'auto-migrated' issue tracked here: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/280